# Counting Questions about Position

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Lets say we have a student organization of 8000 students. 5000 are undergrads and 3000 are master students. There is an organization that has a president position, and  three VP positions.

a) How many ways are there to choose people for this organization from all students?

b) How many was are there to choose so that at least one master student and one undergrad get a position?

c) How many was are there to choose so that the VP position has to be an undergrad and president position can be undergrad or masters.

d) How many was are there to choose so that at least one master student is VP?

I am really new to counting and I was wondering if someone could tell me if my logic is right on these.

a) $8000 \cdot 7999 \cdot 7998\cdot7997$ because you choose someone for the first position and then loose that person from the group and continue until you fill all positions.

b) $4! (\binom{5000}{1}\cdot \binom{3000}{1}\cdot \binom{7998}{2})$ because we choose undergrad for one position, master for the second, and then for the rest we can choose from the rest of the students. There is $4!$ ways to arrange this.

c) $3!\bigg( \binom{5000}{3} \bigg) \cdot \binom{7997}{1}$ We choose three undergrads for the VP positions and then there is $3!$ ways to arrange this and then we choose from the left over group to fill the president position.

d) $\binom{8000}{4} - \binom{5000}{4}$ so we are taking all the positions that have undergrads and master students and then subtracting the total positions without master students.

Comment: I assume there are 3 VP positions based on your answers. Is that correct?

Comment: yes! fixed in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If we assume all the VP positions are different then the first is correct. Otherwise you divide by 3! for the duplicate positions.

b) This is incorrect becuase you will be counting the same solutions multiple times. To see this consider there are 5 masters called a, b, c, d, and e and 3 undergraduates f, g, h. When you select your first master and first undergraduat say a and f then fill the rest of the group with say, b and g and permute all the combinations, well the same combinations could have been acheived if you initially picked b and g and filled the rest of the group with a and f.

I would approach this problem by taking your answer to part a. Then working out how many of those combinations have no masters student and subtracting that. Then subtract the number of ways you can have no undergraduate students to get your answer.

c) This is correct again assuming that the vp positions are all diferent.

d)This is wrong that would be the number of ways of having at least 1 master in some position if all the positions are the same. You haven't dealt with the various permutations. Your also not interested in at least 1 master on the committee becuase the master must hold a vp position.

Comment: My apologies! I was trying to say that these are distinct positions

Comment: For b) would I just say $8000 \cdot 7999 \cdot 7998 \cdot 7997 - 3000\cdot2999\cdot2998\cdot2997$?

Comment: And for d) would it be $\binom{3000}{1} \cdot \binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{7999}{3} \cdot 3!$ because we choose the master student, then choose one of the three VP positions and fill the rest in with the other students? And there is $3!$ ways to arrange the rest of the positions?

Comment: For b that would give you all the commitees with at least 1 under grad because you are doing (all the possibilities) - (all the possibilites with no undergraduates) what about the positiions with no masters?

Comment: For d that doesn't look right what is the 3C1 doing in there I don't follow that. But again what you're describing has the same problem as your initial attempt at b. Be very careful to find a way to count all the answers without double counting any groups. To answer d you want to do (all the possibilites) - (all the possibilities with no master as a vp)

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. For b) We take the total of grads and undergrads and subtract all undergrads and grads, making the equation: $\binom{8000}{4} - \binom{5000}{4} - \binom{3000}{4}$?

Comment: And d) would be $\binom{8000}{4} - \binom{3000}{3}$, meaning all possibilities - no masters as VP. Am I following you correctly?

Comment: that would make b correct. what you're looking for for d is 8000C4 - 7997*(3000C4) becuase each commitee with all undergraduates for vps could have 7997 different presidents.

Answer (score 1):

> For (b), $\binom{5000}{1}\binom{3000}{1}\binom{7998}{2}$ is indeed
> correct for the number of ways to select committee members. But given
> four members, there are not $4!$ possible committees. There are only
> $4$ since each committe is completely determined by who the president
> is, and there are $4$ choices for president.

My apologies, this is incorrect (thank you to G Aker for pointing this out). Since we are choosing from the master and undergrad pool twice, we are double-counting some committees. Instead, you should take the total number of committees and subtract the bad cases, i.e. the cases in which the entire committee is made up of master students or undergraduates. Then once you have the total number of possible committees, think of the possible position assignments.

> Similar thing for (c). $\binom{5000}{3}\binom{7997}{1}$ already gives
> a committee with $3 $ VP's and a president, so there is no more
> re-arranging to do.

Same issue here.

(I am assuming that all of the VP positions are the same, i.e. switching two VP's results in the same committee. It's not quite clear from the problem, but if the three VP positions are distinct, then your answers for (b) and (c) are correct.)

For (d), you forgot to subtract the case when only the president is a master student.

Comment: I disagree that b is correct if the vp postions are distinct. Please see my answer.

Comment: To pick four members for a committee, can't we choose 1 of the 5000 undergrads, then 1 of the 3000 masters, then any 2 of the remaining 7998 students? Alternatively, you can take the total number of committees from (a), then subtract the number of "homogeneous" committees.

Comment: If there are 3 Masters, 3 undergrads and 3 identical spaces on the commitee and we need at least 1 master and at least 1 undergrad on the commitee. If we do the subtracting homogenous solutions method then there are 6C3 - 2 = 18 ways of doing this which is correct. However with your first method you will get 3 * 3 *4 = 36 because you are counting all the combinations twice.

Comment: Ah I see. By choosing from the masters and undergrad pools twice, we are double-counting since the order of choosing can be reversed.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it.